# Why do certain Linux x86_64 system calls require a stub?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, x86-64, system-calls

If one tries to hook certain syscalls via `sys_call_table`-hooking, e.g. `sys_execve` this will fail, because they are indirectly called by a stub. For `sys_execve` this is `stub_execve` (compare assembly code on [LXR](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S#L862)).

But what are these stubs good for? Why do only certain system calls like `execve(2)` and `fork(2)` require a stub and how is this connected to x86_64? Is there a workaround to hook stubbed syscalls (in a Loadable Kernel Module)?

Comment: from the top of this file http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S `Normal syscalls and interrupts don't save a full stack frame, this is only done for syscall tracing, signals or fork/exec et.al.` . So basically the answer is: considering the critical role that this functions play into tracing and debugging we need to save and look at as much registers as possible during each event.

Comment: http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs124/lectures/CS124Lec09.pdf  the slides 21 and 22 make a clear introduction of this stub in most OSes, basically, `Allows the OS’ interrupt service routines to be more uniform` and `OSes frequently use short stubs of assembly code to
invoke their interrupt service routines (ISRs)`  ~ This slide helps me a lot, hope it helpful for you :)

Answer (score 3):

From [here](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.24/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S#395), it says:

> "Certain special system calls that need to save a complete full stack frame."

And I think execve is just one of these special system calls.

From the code of [stub_execve](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.24/source/arch/x86/kernel/entry_64.S#L436), If you want to hook it, at least you can try:

1. Get to understand the meaning of those assembly code and do it by yourself, then you can call your own function in your own assembly code.
2. From the middle of the assembly code, it has a `call sys_execve`, you can replace the address of sys_execve to your own hook function.

Comment: The first link is now broken.